# Android 34 - Webview stopped loading unexpectedly and load once close the activity

Tags: android, webview

We've got a WebView that we're loading under the Application class whenever the app starts. This website is for internal data loading and won't appear to end users.
All was well; till then, we upgraded the application to Android SDK 34.
While loading the WebView, at some point during the loading, unexpectedly, it stops loading and keeps on the same state till we close the application.

Note that we've got another WebView that loads WebView to display web pages.
Is someone having a similar issue? Any clue or solution is appreciated. Thank you